# How to download a file saved on server folder with data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

So i'm having an upload page where you can add files to a database and the files are saved in "cursuri/" with a varchar insert in a mysql table.

Now i want to download the file but i cant(i checked, the file uploaded is in the folder), i keep getting an empty .htm file instead.

I checked the data from the mysql table preda.material(varchar) and it contains an binary_file.dat and inside it the name of the file.

Now the script:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('scripts/connect_to_mysql.php');
$ID_material = (int) $_GET['ID_material'];  
$sql = "SELECT material FROM `preda` WHERE `ID_material` = '$ID_material' "; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=". $info['material']);        

/* print "Cursuri/".$info['material'] ." <br>"; */
}

?>
```

Comment: Off topic, but you should never pass a GET variable directly into your sql. Someone could easily insert some malicious code and get access to your codebase just from that.

Comment: I second that too. Also try using the DB index when move_uploaded_file(), as this prevents overwriting files of the same name. The index will be different for each file uploaded.

Comment: It's for a project so it wont see the light of ...the internet. 
I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's internal or external, always follow best practices. In fact, you're simply ensuring that your SQL syntax is valid, it doesn't even have to be about security (though that's a desirable side effect).

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: No, i was talking about my download script... but that's a really nice article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=". $info['material']);
```

This only sets an HTTP header telling the recipient (the browser) that the body of the HTTP response contains file data for a file named XYZ. It does not in itself attach a file or enables the browser to get the file from somewhere. You will still have to output the actual file data yourself. See [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile).